# Office Add-on with dynamic/reactive content

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to develop an Add-In for OneNote. I'm trying to add a table where the user can click the first column to toggle through 4-5 icons.

Image of different Icons

[image: Image of different Icons]

I can't find a way to do this. Is there a way to react to click notifications on the inserted content, say a button on the first column of each row in the table?

I've noticed that the ToDo tag has two states, but creating a new Tag doesn't allow more than one image. Is there a way to add a Tag that has more than one state?

Comment: I don't think there's a way of creating a custom NoteTag. I think it has to be one of [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/onenote/onenote.notetagtype). Also, the [TableCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/onenote/onenote.tablecell) object doesn't support events.

Comment: You can create custom tags. Not supported in the UWP app, but available in the win32 version: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/add-create-and-find-tags-in-microsoft-onenote/

Comment: You mean through the UI. Yes. I thought you meant programmatically.